# How to update a COM+ applications and create its msi file using PowerShell?

Tags: window, windows-installer, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, com+

I have a **COM+ application** installed on my machine which has two components. This COM+ application was created using an `SetupCom.exe` file which was made using C# code some years bac. It used to install and create a `COM+ msi file`, but now I don't have access to that code, and I need to remove one component from this COM+ application - which is no longer in use.

So, I searched using google and I found some PowerShell scripts that remove the components from the COM+ application, but they don't create the `msi` file. I need this updated COM+ application `msi\installer` file so that I can install it on multiple machines.

Below is the Script which removes the component from COM+ application, but doesn't create an updated `msi` file.

```ps
$comCatalog = New-Object -ComObject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$appColl = $comCatalog.GetCollection("Applications")
$appColl.Populate()

$app = $appColl | where {$_.Name -eq "COMAPPNAME"}
$compColl = $appColl.GetCollection("Components", $app.Key)
$compColl.Populate()

$index = 0
foreach($component in $compColl) {

    if ($component.Name -eq "SOMECOMPONENT.NAME") {
        $compColl.Remove($index)
        $compColl.SaveChanges()
    }

    $index++
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing the below, I remembered having written something similar before. Here it is: **[Would this method of installing COM+ work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019329/would-this-method-of-installing-com-work/23022625#23022625)**

---

There is support in [**all major deployment tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617506/application-setup/51618424#51618424) (thee main bullet point links) to do **COM+ deployment**. [**WiX**](http://www.wixtoolset.org) may provide the most flexible features for COM+ installation, but I have never used them.

COM+ deployment has always been a bit strange to deal with. Despite all my years doing deployment I have only done it a few times. And several times I have had a lot of problems with it. I even had a guy make a basic "hello world" COM+ application that I sent to a deployment vendor to illustrate how they did not do COM+ properly. No luck.

***Typically I have ended up exporting a COM+ installer MSI from the Component Services*** (Launch suggestion: <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + tap <kbd>R</kbd> type `comexp.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>). After setting up an application as you want it running, you right click it in the list and export an MSI file (in your case I guess it should already be set up):

[image: Exporting COM+ application]

This exported MSI file is not - shall we say - the greatest thing since sliced bread. If you want to modify it, it will quickly break in some fashion. There is an undocumented **APL file** in there with **COM+ settings** that I never understood how to handle on my own. Just use the MSI as it is - if you can.

---

***Some Links***: I took it a bit far with these links, just go for the bolded ones.

- [Creating Installation Packages for COM+ Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/windows/desktop/cossdk/creating-installation-packages-for-com--applications)
- [**Understanding COM+ Application Installation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732533(v=ws.11))
- [C# - Retrieve properties of a COM+ component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152821/c-sharp-retrieve-properties-of-a-com-component)
- [Automating COM+ Administration](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/windows/desktop/cossdk/automating-com--administration)
- [COM+:Library vs Server Application](http://community.installshield.com/archive/index.php?t-113045.html)
- [COM+ Application installation woes](http://community.installshield.com/archive/index.php?t-123700.html)
- [The COM+ Event System](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=19629) (loosely coupled event (**LCE**) system)